# How SecurityException will redirect to a login page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my code, I would like to allow access only for admin and display a login page for other users.

```
[System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission(System.Security.SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Admin")]
public ActionResult AccessUserData()
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `AuthorizeAttribute` for permission control in MVC views. [Here's a solid MSFT article about it](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api).

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult AccessUserData() {}
```

> Will SecurityException redirect to a login page?

Nope! It will simply throw the exception and the application will redirect to it's error page, by default.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks! I'm also curious about System.Security.SecurityAction.Demand, so what kind of action it will take? Same as SecurityException by directly to an error page?

Comment: @Gabriel  When passed a `SecurityAction.Demand`, the `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` will throw a `SecurityException` if the current user (which, in a web application, is the user who is assigned run to the Application Pool in IIS) is unauthorised for _any_ of the calls higher in the call stack.